# float lef outlook signature solution

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

im trying to make an outlook signature with html.
I dont know how can i do a signature email with 3 rows
[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0g5W.png)
[what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0MTt.png)

There is my code:

```
<section id="2" style="float: left; position:relative; margin-left: 230px; width: 250px;">
        <div id="user" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <h1 style="margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px !important; font-size: 20px; color: #414042; font-weight:bolder; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Adriano Medeiros</h1>
            <h2 style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px !important;font-size: 16px; color: #414042; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">MARKETING DIRECTOR</h2>
            <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px !important; font-size: 14px; color: #414042; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">Dpt. Marketing e Comunicação</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="email" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="email"  style="width: 20px; position: absolute; margin-top: 15px;">
            <p style="margin-top:15px; float: left; margin-left: 40px; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #414042; font-weight: bold;">Adriano.medeiros@homa.pt</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="3" style="float: left; width: 273px; ">
        <div class="line" style=" margin-top:10px;border-left:2px solid #D9AB28; height: 130px;position: absolute;"></div>
        <div class="contacts" style="margin-left: 30px;">
            <div class="telefone">
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="phone number"style="float:left; margin-right:20px; width: 20px;">
                <h2 style="padding-top: 7px; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #414042; font-weight: bold;">960000000000 | Ext. 22044</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="smartphone number">
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABUAAAAjCAYAAAB7NEEmAAAACXBIWXMAABYlAAAWJQFJUiTwAAAA90lEQVRIie2WPW7DMAxGHw2PGXKDyEA8NzdpFs9tTlZ3jZbmBj2Cu0ZDfYM2J2CHUqmHAjEkLwLCRZTE70H/oqgqS1u1OLEoaB2d4MUBLoM1tp2OAKKqBC/PwEsGMNqh7bSX8xEHfFrjCRgSYDvg0fym5m/Kp7bTfeoQg5c3A7vpRqWMcGpXfTlHqizo1vxdJivqtxWwsso6Exr1q7LWtBxovF7vmayoH8qa/h16h8I+eEl6qUx3/TTrSd8DMAQvYwLXAZv/oFjHhkybu6YfQGPlYtDe8qR+TrCcj6yBrxmxr8DTjLimajv9Bg7A5UbwLeCF3wRt/AFdyDg/DvcalwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="smartphone number" style="float:left; margin-right: 20px; margin-top: 5px; width: 20px;">
                <h2 style="padding-top:15px; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #414042; font-weight: bold;">2222222222</h2>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word for rendering message bodies. In Word, two HTML elements that support a subset of the cascading style sheets properties are called out: `DIV` and `P`. Read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Note, Outlook for desktop doesn't support base64 images. You'd need to attach an image and then use the `cid:` attribute to refer to the attached image.